# Is there a way for Omnis Studio to only look into a specific folder when calling FileOps?

Tags: omnis-studio-10, omnis-studio-8

Is there anyway to prevent a user in Omnis Studio from navigating around in various directory's on a machine?

for example.

I want the end user to import a delimited file. I would do something like:
`FileOps.$getfilename(&cPath[,cPrompt,cFilter,cInitialDirectory,iAppflags])`

How do I prevent them from being able to navigate outside the initial directory that is defined? (when the file dialog is open).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still in Omnis Classic, so excuse me if there is a better way, but if this was what I wanted to do I would build my own window inside Omnis and ask the user which file they want to select.

```
Fileops.$getfiles
```

might be what you want to use